# PlayerPrefs.SetInt Stops code below from running

Tags: unity, c#

This is the code...

```
void storeStarData()
{
    // Code to store star data in PlayerPrefs...
    Debug.Log("Writing to PlayerPrefs");
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totStars", NumOfStars);
    int i = 0;
    Debug.Log("test");
    while (i < NumOfStars)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starID" + i, StarIDID[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starName" + i, StarName[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starHIP" + i, StarIDHIP[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starHD" + i, StarIDHD[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starHR" + i, StarIDHR[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starGL" + i, StarIDGL[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starBF" + i, StarIDBF[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starRA" + i, StarRA[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starDec" + i, StarDec[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starMag" + i, StarMag[(i)]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("starCI" + i, StarCI[(i)]);
        Debug.Log("star " + i + " complete");
        i++;
    }
    PlayerPrefs.Save();

    i = 0;
    int ok = 0;
    while (i < NumOfStars)
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("starID" + i) != null)
        {
            ok++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Debug.Log(ok);
}
```

And this is the Debug.Log output that I am getting...

[image: Debug.Log output]

As you can see, the program gets up to the First Debug Log `Debug.Log("Writing to PlayerPrefs");` But then stops before the `Debug.Log("test");`.

After removing `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totStars", NumOfStars);` The program gets to the `Debug.Log("test");`. So it is the PlayerPrefs.SetInt causing the issue.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does contain NumOfStar?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "stops"? The program crashes? It exits the function? It freezes?

Comment: NumOfStars is an integer that contains the number 36. The editor doesn't freeze or hang. The program just doesn't execute anything after that

Comment: Sounds like there may be an error interrupting the execution of this routine. Can you check your console for warnings or errors, in case you might have toggled those off?

Comment: @DMGregory, no errors were returned. Turns out that PlayerPrefs doesn't play well with System Threading or Tasks. Once I ran the function on the main thread, It started to work well.

Comment: Oh. Yeah, most of the Unity API methods are main thread only. So are the errors that get logged to the console. What most likely happened is you tried to use PlayerPrefs off the main thread, it threw an exception saying "this must be run on the main thread" but you didn't catch and print that exception so instead the thread was killed silently. This is why it's important to include context in your question - if we could see this was being run in a thread we could have solved it for you right away. Please post your solution as an Answer!

Comment: Don't use PlayerPrefs to store game state. You have access to `System.IO` and `JsonUtility`, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Unity doesn't play very well with System.Threading as I was running this function off the main thread to prevent the GUI from freezing (I am dealing with almost 120,000 records in the list).

Once I ran the function on the main thread, all the problems disappeared and PlayerPrefs started working normally.

Comment: For saving on this magnitude, you might want to consider using System.IO methods to write the data to your own file. That can happen on its own thread so it doesn't impact your framerate.

Comment: Moving away from PlayerPrefs and using a Singleton script to store the data in the list data structure is much more efficient. Thanks @DMGregory

Comment: Is there a gimmicky way to force the player prefs to be read on the main thread without refactoring too much code?

Comment: never mind, I was able to fix the issue anyway. Btw, the answer helped a lot